# xPage add placeBar item

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I want to add placeBar label to the right.. 
PlaseBar title appears as a text on left, all buttons/items appears on right. But there is no option to add just a text/label as an item. If I cannot add a lebel then how can I style the button to hide borders?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `basicLeafNode` to your placeBarActions

```
            <xe:this.placeBarActions>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="need a label here"
                    enabled="false"
                    styleClass="labelPlaceBar">
                </xe:basicLeafNode>
```

and give it a class "labelPlaceBar".

Set enabled to "false". This way it won't change mouse cursor hovering over the label.

Use class "labelPlaceBar" in css to hide label's border and background for normal mode and for hovering:

```
.labelPlaceBar a, .labelPlaceBar a:hover  {
     border: none;
     background: transparent;
}
```

Then it will show the label just as a label.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question on the button styling: add `border: none` to your buttons in the place bar by adding this to your custom css file:

```
.lotusPlaceBar .lotusBtn {
    border: none;
}
```

This will target buttons in the place bar only.

You can also add your own class to a specific button and then target that class only.

The most simple solution is probably to just add inline CSS to your button:

```
<xp:button value="need a label here" id="button3" style="border:none"></xp:button>
```

Comment: that would remove border from all buttons

Comment: Sure, that's why I am saying that you can add your own class to a specific button and then change the border for that class only (or even add border:none directly to that specific button)